# Unable to Returning function to main HTML body javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I call the function from a click of the submit button here, and retrieving the entered text works fine.

```
<button class="btn btnEmail" id="emailBtn" onclick="emailUser.getEmailInput();">Submit</button>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="writeMail(this.emailInput)" />
```

It seems the function is not able to return the value of emailInput to html main body as I cannot use it with my writemail function.

the getEmail function:

```
let emailUser = {
    getEmailInput: function() {
        this.emailInput = document.getElementById('emailInput').value;
        document.getElementById("emailOutput").innerHTML = this.emailInput;
        return(this.emailInput);
    }
};
```

the writeMail function:

```
function writeMail(email) {
    console.log(email);
    localStorage.setItem('email',email);
    let theEmail = localStorage.getItem('email');
    console.log(theEmail);
}
```

Comment: All of this is part of a project that is due relatively soon. I am extremely horrific at coding aha and am willing to pay if someone would be able to aid me with finishing this extremely simple piece of code project.

Comment: In brief can you explain what exactly you are trying to do with this code, i mean what you want that code should do when you click the button

Comment: Its a recruitment app, basically just 3 different screens that can be linked between with a navbar, this screen is just taking email inputs, saving them and allowing them to be read and edited later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in `onclick="writeMail(this.emailInput)"` will refer to the element itself. i:e `input with type button`.

Instead pass the value of other input using `document.getElementById('emailInput').value)`.

```js
function writeMail(email) {
  console.log(email);
  localStorage.setItem('email', email);
  let theEmail = localStorage.getItem('email');
  console.log(theEmail);
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="emailInput">
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="writeMail(document.getElementById('emailInput').value)">
```

Comment: works perfect man, this also helped me understand alot about how weird javascript works as it runs without throwing up errors sometimes and you gotta find them yourself

Comment: @cola465 - If the answer solves your question, mark it as accepted in order to indicate the problem has been resolved.